# Why is the JSDoc comment not shown when filtering mapped keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, jsdoc

I'm trying to create a config type for a class. I want the type to have all the properties as optional but without the functions of the of the class. Similar to "Partial" but without functions. I have it working but the IDE no longer shows the jsdoc comments.

Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeAKgPigXigG8BYAKCkqgG0AFKFBKAawhDiSiygEMBnKAAosdALpQIAD2AQEAEwEAxAK4IAxsBSIoAfigIIANwgAnKAC4otAJSidlkbVEBucgF9XZcmoA2-AbSmfNqkFFQA9ABUkeRUlJFQAFIAynJwalAAtsp8wFB8ABZwAO5QSHBmAJIAIp5xUJHhsVRgygBGPigZCDyZ0IQARAOezZRRMWFUCZVQaQgA5HnFPAh5wHBQBTzGUMAFKAKI0IywiKhoo-FNk1CtHV1lCILWxOSXbu5vZGqIuVA-yHQlnggMwgRMwQQeEIRB6fQsUAGMlyAw83l+eQB5wATAjaDwTJoeD4MODIdDiHCIJYkRAUR4gA

Here's what I have:

```
type Config<T> = {
                [P in keyof T as (T[P] extends Function ? never : P)]?: T[P];
            };

class Person {
                /**
                 * JSdoc must show for ID;
                 */
                public name = "";

                /**
                 * I don't want to have this one in Config
                 */
                public fn() {

                }
            }

            const config: Config<Person> = {name : "test"};
            const config2 : Partial<Person> = {name: "test"};
```

With config2 the jsdoc hint shows but for Config it doesn't. Does anybody know how to get this to work?

Comment: This is just a limitation of TS/JSDoc. The docs get lost when operating on the types.

Answer (score 0):

Key filter will lose JSDoc. But Omit and Pick won't!

Try:

```
type Config<T> = Omit<T, {
   [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? P : never)
}[keyof T]>
```